# Replace a substring specified by a range in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a string, a function that changes a string and a range.
I want to get a function that replaces the initial substring with the modified

For example:

```
val initialString = "abcdefgh" 
// range for getting substring, thus substring is "abc"
val (start, end) = (0, 3) 
// function for changes a string
def f(s: String) = s + "@" 
val modifiedSubstring = f(initialString.substring(start, end)) // "abc@"
// I don't know hot to implement desiredFunction
val res = desiredFunction(initialString, start, end, f) // "abc@defgh"
```

Comment: what's the significance of `start` and `end`? how do they lead to `ab@cdef`?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I modified the question

Comment: `initialString.substring(0, start) + f(initialString.substring(start, end)) + initialString.substring(end)` What's the catch?

Comment: @Dima yes, you are right, my head doesn't work tonight, i asked stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use non-inclusive ranges, this is standard when operating on strings in Scala, Java, and probably other languages. I'll assume non-inclusive ranges.

`slice` and `patch` are useful here:

```
def applyOnSlice(s: String, start: Int, end: Int, fn: String => String) =
  s.patch(
    start,
    fn(s.slice(start, end)),
    end)
```

Comment: Yes, I agreed about non-inclusive ranges, I included end range because of carelessness.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are after, note that I had to add the `+1`on the indexes because from your example your range is inclusive, while the String functions in Scala are not.

```
def desiredFunction(string: String, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int, replaceFunc: (String) => String) = {

  // Get the first part
  val a = string.substring(0, startIndex)

  // Get the middle part and do your replacing
  val b = replaceFunc(string.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1))

  // Get the last part
  val c = string.substring(endIndex + 1)

  // Put it all together and return
  a + b + c
}
```